# Is there any spinach for DotNet?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, bdd, specflow, spinach

I'm interested in testing Spinach on .Net, does anybody knows if there is any frameworks based on it for .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. State of the art in BDD on .net is still specflow.